# How to replace symbols from object in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, object, replace

I'm trying to replace symbols from object in python, I used

```
df_summary.replace('\(|\)!,"-', '', regex=True)
```

[image]

but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Please use `inplace=True`

Answer (score 1):

The replace function is not *in place*. This means that your dataframe will be unchanged, and the result is returned as the return value of the replac  function.
You can the the inplace parameter of replace:

```
df_summary.replace('\(|\)!,"-', '', regex=True, inplace=True)
```

Most of the pandas functions are note in place and require if needed either the inplace argument, or the assignement of the result to a new dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

You can either do

```
df_summary.replace('\(|\)!,"-', '', regex=True, inplace=True)
```

or

```
df_summary = df_summary.replace('\(|\)!,"-', '', regex=True)
```

When you only do `df_summary.replace...`, this line returns you a pandas list. You forgot to save it. Please add comments to further assist you

Answer (score 0):

Apart from addind `regex=True` or setting the result to `df_summary` again,  your are using a pattern:

```
`\(|\)!,"-`
```

That matches matches either `(` OR the string `\)!,"-`

As you are referring to symbols, and you want to replace all separate chars `(` `)` `!` `,` `"` `-` you can use a repeated character class `[()!,"-]+` to replace multiple consecutive matches at once.

```
df_summary.replace('[()!,"-]+', '', regex=True, inplace=True)
```